# Is Logical semantic layer instead Materialized semantic layer in a medium/Large DWH practical

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I  am seeing Lot of these  i.e. instead of extra ETL layer to materialize dimensional schema create  Logical views  on Top of Base layer.

When i think of it specially for Type 2 SCD it the logical becomes very complex with DV also . Already maintaining a 3NF historical model as base layer is quite challenging  so i am not considering that .

When i think about it in a moderate /Large Warehouse  >20 TB with couple of large dimensions/Context table is it worth if users are  doing detail level queries?
Understand with MVs/Join Indexes ,shrunken Logical views, or Extract aggregated data to High end Reporting tool with large memory etc. can answer many reporting need with logical view.

Answer (score 1):

They're a great solution if you want to cripple your data warehouse.

A logical / view-based layer may work for the most trivial examples of a star schema, but as soon as you have any complexity you'll be implementing the work of materialisation for *every* query rather than just once.

Comment: I agree with you. i believe also it is a ploy by many companies to  sell their  shiny "Tools".